# How to set border for UITableView iOS 7?

Tags: uitableview, ios7, ios7.1

There is no side borders for the UITableView in iOS 7. I have tried the following to change the border color and width:

```
tableView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

Still I don't get the border for UITableView.

```
tableView.separatorColor
```

Even setting this can't help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: @ArunB: using this code you can make border of UItableView

Comment: did you import 'QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h' frameWork